# emacs "comint-send-string: Buffer *spam* has no process" in python-mode

Tags: shell, emacs, process

I have a simple set of emacs lisp lines that I use to insert my initials and a time/datestamp, but this has stopped working in some modes (e.g., python-mode). In these modes it throws the error `comint-send-string: Buffer *spam* has no process`, where 'spam' is the buffer I'm trying to add my timestamp to.

The lisp lines are:

`(defun msl-insert-datetime () (interactive) (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M ABC: ")))`
`(global-set-key [(control c)(control d)] 'msl-insert-datetime)`

This works fine in buffers of various modes (text mode, lisp mode, etc.), inserting something like `2020-05-20 21:44 ABC:`.  But in Python mode (where I do much of my programming) I get the message above instead.

Any suggestions would be most welcome! I'm running Emacs 26.3 (build 2) on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd> is probably bound in `python-mode` (presumably to something which wants to talk to an inferior process).

```
(global-set-key [(control c)(control d)] 'msl-insert-datetime)
```

This binds the sequence in the global key map -- which is the *lowest-priority* keymap -- and you've chosen a sequence which is reserved for major modes.

> Sequences consisting of ‘C-c’ followed by a control character or a digit are reserved for major modes.

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Key Binding Conventions`

As such, it's not surprising that some major modes are binding that in their (higher-priority) major mode keymaps.

There are certain other sequences you can more safely use in the global map, without worrying about them being used by other keymaps:

> Sequences consisting of ‘C-c’ and a letter (either upper or lower
>   case) are reserved for users.  Function keys <F5> through <F9>
>   without modifier keys are also reserved for users to define.

Note that you can use such sequences as prefix bindings, so *lots* of custom commands might hang off of <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (for example).

If you have Super and/or Hyper modifier keys on your keyboard, they are typically also unused by Emacs (at least by default).

I also remove the default <kbd>C-z</kbd> binding and use it as another prefix for custom bindings.

Lastly, I highly recommend reading https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs to gain an understanding of keymaps and their priorities.

Comment: This gave me the solution I needed. I just changed the lisp command to `(global-set-key [(control c)(d)] 'msl-insert-datetime)` and now it works as desired in Python-mode. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  I would suggest switching to the `kbd` method of specifying key sequences, because that means you can take the key description used by Emacs (e.g. when you ask it with `C-h k`), and plug that directly into `kbd` and as a result you'd never be left guessing about how to describe any key.  In this instance it would be `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'msl-insert-datetime)`, because Emacs describes that sequence as `C-c d`.